# What is the syntactic function (if there is any) of the prefix in some German verbs?

Tags: syntax, german, x-bar-theory, phrases, prefixes

Consider the following sentence:

> "*Ich rufe dich **an***".

It is a very simple Standard German sentence with the verb "*anrufen*", the unusual thing about it is this prefix that comes with the verb, it goes to the end. Does it have any syntactic classification? Or is it considered just a part of the verb that was moved?

If it is just a movement, how would it be represented in a tree using X-bar theory? Would it be in the specifier, a complement, or the core of a phrase, if so, what kind of phrase?

Comment: These are [separable verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb), and a few other languages have them too.

Comment: Perhaps a cross-post on [German.SE](http://german.stackexchange.com/users/43657) would be in order ?